# Logic behind "OR"? $P(\bar{A}\cap B) + P(\bar{B}\cap A)$ Vs $P(A \cup B)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

In a deck of $52$ cards , find the probability of drawing a king or a black card .

Let probability of drawing a black card be P(A)
Let probability of drawing a king be P(B)
As drawing king , drawing black card are not mutually exclusive ,
by "OR" I mean english word or in the following explanation.
I thought taking a king of spade or club will violate the condition black "OR" king thinking that when I take a king of spade or club will fulfil both the conditions. so I did as 
P(A OR B) = P(A) + P(B) - 2 P(A$\cap$B)

= $ \frac{4}{52} + \frac{26}{52} - 2 * \frac{2}{52}$

= $ \frac{26}{52}$

But the book told as per conventions as per the formula 
P(A OR B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A$\cap$B) = $28/52$

Why is my reasoning wrong ?

when I draw a black spade or black club , won't I violate the condition that it is black "OR" king ? so only I subtracted possibilities of drawing black spade or black club . so I subtracted $2/52$ and got $26/52$ instead of $28/52$.

If I can also apply my reasoning as

P(black or king) = P(King that is not black) + P(Black card that is not a king)

= $2/52 + 24/52 = 26/52 $

Please help me in knowing where I am going wrong in reasoning

So I am saying the formula to be used here is $P(\bar{A}\cap B) + P(\bar{B}\cap A)$ and book says the formula to be used here is $P(A  \cup B)$. So in my logic for OR it is real A or B , there is not option for A and B.

My formula for for this question -> $P(\bar{A}\cap B) + P(\bar{B}\cap A)$  = $P(A) + P(B) -2\times P(A \cap B)$

Book's formula(conventional) for this question ->  $P(A  \cup B)$ = $P(A) + P(B) - 1 \times P(A \cap B)$

Comment: Note that you formula exclude the case where both of the conditions are met, so we need to add one $P(A\cap B)$ on the left side and that will make the two formula completly the same.

Comment: Ya Thats my question how in A or B  I can add a value for A "AND" B ? it is OR right , so only one among A or B

Comment: P(A OR B) = $P(\bar{A}\cap B) + P(\bar{B}\cap A) + P(A\cap B)$

Comment: let me reason by basic english , if someone asks you to take either   food "OR" water , I have to take only one and how can I take both food and water .                                                      If someone asking you to choose one subject either maths or science for higher studies , we have to choose only one, how can we take both science and maths , your reasoning or the conventional formula compels me to take both

Comment: Please leave the formula , please explain the flaw in my reasoning by logical analysis .

Comment: Can you check my edit and tell me whether it helped you?

Comment: It seem you are interested in exclusive OR (XOR) instead of OR, so please next time ask you question clearer.

Comment: No I am not sticking to XOR or OR . I am asking which fits this problem I have quoted in question .

Comment: Beacuse you want to exclude te posibility of black king, you are obviously refereing to XOR

Comment: the or i meant at many places is the or in question just english or and  not anything else . please don't make it xor

Answer (score 3):

This an **English** problem, not a mathematics problem.

The OR operator in Boolean logic is **defined** by: A  OR  B  is true if A is true , or B is true , or **both** are true.  The truth table for a OR-gate reflects this.

The XOR, exclusive-OR operator in Boolean logic is *defined* by: A  XOR  B  is true if A is true , or B is true , but not if  **both** are true.  The truth table for a XOR-gate reflects this.

So the question is:  did the writer of the question have the OR type of *or*,  or the XOR type of *or* in mind?

Consider this:  If you were told that you could be charged if you were speeding or driving drunk, would you even consider the defense that you were doing both, and therefore immune to charges?

Comment: so for this problem "In a deck of 52 cards , find the probability of drawing a king or a black card ." if A is the event of drawing black card , B is event of drawing king. now is it A XOR B or A OR be here ?. which is apt . based on which I will decide if book is wrong or right. I am saying apt would be A xor B

Comment: i while writing question meant the english "or". not anything else.

Comment: I think you're wrong. I believe that the common English usage in using *or* to connect two **non-exclusive** possibilities is to mean the OR type of logic.

Comment: I also think the question is poorly worded...

Comment: I don't think so that the question is poorly worded. It is in simple english.it cannot be simple than "In a deck of 52 cards , find the probability of drawing a king or a black card"

Comment: If it's so simple, why is this question even here?  You **don't know** what the word "or" in this context means. **No one** knows for sure what it means.  That's why we have lawyers to draw up agreements, and courts to decide what the words actually mean.  You have perfectly analyzed the  mathematical implications of the two possible meanings, and that's all you can hope to do.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the OR operator is understood in the inclusive sense, that is A OR B is true if either A is true, B is true, or both are true. Therefore
$$ P(A \cup B) = P(A \text{ OR } B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \text{ AND } B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B), $$
rather than the formula you wrote.

Comment: Ya formula you gave  is absolutely right . what is wrong in my reasoning ? that was my question . leave the formula, just spot the error in my analysis

Comment: see my second way of reasoning the same in my question

Comment: if you want formula the formula I am arguing for is $P(\bar{A}\cap B) + P(\bar{B}+A)$

Comment: I have updated the answer with the 2 formula's that can be used . My question is why not it is the first one $P(\bar{A}\cap B) + P(\bar{B}\cap A)$

Answer (score 2):

I think that formula you are using is wrong. It should be:

P(A OR B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A$\cap$B), which will give the true answer. I don't get it why we would exclude the number twice? We only need to exclude just once, beacuse the king of spades and the king of clubs were included twice.

---

First try to make things clearer to the reader. OR means the same as $\lor$, which means the either one of the condition is met or both ar met. But it seems that you are interested in exclusive OR (XOR) which is usually represented by $\oplus$. The formula for this is:

$$P(A \oplus B) = P(A \cup B) \cap \overline{P(A \cap B)}$$

But your formula would do the trick.

This formula first add the probability of either of the condition is fulfiled and then excludes the probability when both od them are met. And your formula add the probability of just one condition separately.

But anyway you'll get the same result.

Comment: Ya formula you gave  is absolutely right . what is wrong in my reasoning ? that was my question . leave the formula, just spot the error in my analysis

Comment: see my second way of reasoning the same in my question

Comment: if you want formula the formula I am arguing for is $P(\bar{A}\cap B) + P(\bar{B}+A)$

Comment: In the edit you made you forgot to add $P(A\cap B)$, which is the probability when two of the conditions are met

Comment: Ya Thats my question how in A or B , I can add a value for A "AND" B ? it is OR , so only one among A or B .

Comment: I am doubting this statement "In this case there is a posibility when both of the conditions are satisfied so we must include it also and we do that by". why should we take that "both" case . even I have given an example for math or science choosing below the question. my example seems to be reasonable . so try to point the flaw in that example itself so that I can understand

Comment: coming by your formula .a union b is different from a or b . a union b means a or b or both (this is by definition). then how can we use that here in this problem.

Comment: I got your point. You want to exclude the probability of drawing a black king?

Comment: yes thats the point I am making

Comment: Check the last edit, I think you'll understand

Comment: so you agree that the book is wrong ?

Comment: You can read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or. If the book formula relates to XOR then it's obviously wrong, but if it relates to OR then it's true.

Comment: what fits the problem given ?

Comment: The problem that you post is related to XOR, which means the the solution given in the book for this problem is wrong.